# How to stop function being called non stop in lua

Tags: lua, scripting

I am busy reading the programming in lua 4th edition book and I am struggling with chapter two. The program essentially prints a chess board with 8 queens that are placed in a way that none of them can attack each other. What I am struggling to figure out is why it prints the boards multiple times.

I have went over the code step by step and once the print solution has finished printing the first board I thought it would just end the function and then jump back to the main but for some reason it keeps looping. I am also very new to lua and have just come from C so still getting used to it all.

Image of one of the boards it outputs. The Xs are the queens - https://ibb.co/KsT3R8X

```
N = 8 -- board size

-- check whether position (n,c) is free from attacks
function isplaceok (a, n, c)
    for i = 1, n - 1 do -- for each queen already placed
        if (a[i] == c) or -- same column?
        (a[i] - i == c - n) or -- same diagonal?
        (a[i] + i == c + n) then -- same diagonal?
            return false -- place can be attacked
        end
    end
    return true -- no attacks; place is OK
end

-- print a board
function printsolution (a)
    for i = 1, N do -- for each row
        for j = 1, N do -- and for each column
            -- write "X" or "-" plus a space
            io.write(a[i] == j and "X" or "-", " ")
        end
        io.write("\n")
    end
    io.write("\n")
end

-- add to board 'a' all queens from 'n' to 'N'
function addqueen (a, n)
    if n > N then -- all queens have been placed?
        printsolution(a)
    else -- try to place n-th queen
        for c = 1, N do
            if isplaceok(a, n, c) then
                a[n] = c -- place n-th queen at column 'c'
                addqueen(a, n + 1)
            end
        end
    end
end

-- run the program
addqueen({}, 1)
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste the code into the body of your question. This makes easier for people to just drop it into a debug environment. If they have to write the code from an image it usually means you will get less engagement and by extension answers.

Comment: My apologies I will paste it. Only reason I did not was because when I copy it from the pdf it does not look as neat.

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is printing all 92 possible solutions for the 8x8 chessboard.
Which is likely the intention, so it would appear to be working correctly.

To stop after we find 1 solution we can add a variable `found` to the program:

```
local found = false

-- print a board
function printsolution (a)
    for i = 1, N do -- for each row
        for j = 1, N do -- and for each column
            -- write "X" or "-" plus a space
            io.write(a[i] == j and "X" or "-", " ")
        end
        io.write("\n")
    end
    io.write("\n")
    found = true
end

-- add to board 'a' all queens from 'n' to 'N'
function addqueen (a, n)
    if n > N then -- all queens have been placed?
        printsolution(a)
    else -- try to place n-th queen
        for c = 1, N do
            if isplaceok(a, n, c) and found == false then
                a[n] = c -- place n-th queen at column 'c'
                addqueen(a, n + 1)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This `found` variable stops the continued recursion of the existing loops as we move back up the stack.

---

Now why is it that this code works this way, where are all the solutions coming from?

That has to do with the `for` loop in `addqueen`:

```
    for c = 1, N do
        if isplaceok(a, n, c) then
            a[n] = c
            addqueen(a, n + 1)
        end
    end
```

Each loop of the for loop sends the code deeper by recursively calling `addqueen`. The stack will never be deeper then 9 as that is the limit set by the `N` 
The first solution after 114 calls to `addqueen` is this one:

```
X - - - - - - - 
- - - - X - - - 
- - - - - - - X 
- - - - - X - - 
- - X - - - - - 
- - - - - - X - 
- X - - - - - - 
- - - X - - - -
```

The 5th solution is the first time we will have come back to our original call of `addqueen`, you can see the first X has moved from 1x1 to 1x2(n=1 c=2, second step of our original for loop):

```
- X - - - - - - 
- - - X - - - - 
- - - - - X - - 
- - - - - - - X 
- - X - - - - - 
X - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - X - 
- - - - X - - -
```

In the end we call `addqueen` 1952 times for the program to check all the possible solutions.

You can adjust the code to print a value of the depth to get a better idea of how the stack looks as the program runs:

```
-- add to board 'a' all queens from 'n' to 'N'
function addqueen (a, n)
    print(n .. "↓")
    if n > N then -- all queens have been placed?
        printsolution(a)
    else -- try to place n-th queen
        for c = 1, N do
            if isplaceok(a, n, c) then
                a[n] = c -- place n-th queen at column 'c'
                addqueen(a, n + 1)
            end
        end
    end
    print(n - 1 .. "↑")
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it has greatly helped me with the understanding of this question.  I was attempting to do something like this but was struggling with figuring out where all the solutions were coming from which you answered really well!

Comment: I am new to lua and still getting used to the basic and how things look vs its equivalent in c. There is a piece of code "a[n] = c" and I just want to make sure I understand what it does. Is it saying assign c to nth part in the array named a?

Comment: @ExileVoid `a[n] = c` is assigning `c` to the key `n` in the table `a`. in lua a table has 2 parts an array part and a hash part. the array part is only defined when you do something like `a = {'a', 'b', 'c'}` if you do `a[1] = 'a'` it would go into the hash part until the table is resize and the array part is evaluated again.

Comment: Very minor note: `found == false` is probably better written as `not found`.

Comment: @val `not found` is valid for both if `found = false` or if `found = nil` making closer to 
`found ~= true`, it is mostly just my personal preference to be explicit with false checks in lua

Comment: Thank you once again, clears it all up. I will start learning a bit more about tables.